# Combine the list rows values as comma separated by its key using java 8

Tags: java, arrays, json, java-8, gson

My input is a JsonArray with dynamic attributes and values.

```
[
 {
  "id": "1",
  "name": "abc",
  "gender": "F"
 },
{
  "id": "2",
  "name": "dgc",
  "address": "MDU"
 },{
  "id": "3",
  "name": "ghf",
  "gender": "M"
 },
]
```

Expecting the output as below:

```
{
"id": "1,2,3",
"name": "abc,dgc,ghf",
"gender": "F,M" 
"address":"MDU"
}
```

I am expecting the logic which will read the dynamic attributes in the JsonArray and combining the values as a comma separated one. By using those values need to create a JsonObject with key.

Comment: Where are you stuck doing this? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
  public JsonNode test() throws JsonProcessingException {
        String jsonArray = "[\n" +
                " {\n" +
                "  \"id\": \"1\",\n" +
                "  \"name\": \"abc\",\n" +
                "  \"gender\": \"F\"\n" +
                " },\n" +
                "{\n" +
                "  \"id\": \"2\",\n" +
                "  \"name\": \"dgc\",\n" +
                "  \"address\": \"MDU\"\n" +
                " },\n" +
                " {\n" +
                "  \"id\": \"3\",\n" +
                "  \"name\": \"ghf\",\n" +
                "  \"gender\": \"M\"\n" +
                " }\n" +
                "]";

        // Parse the JSON array
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(jsonArray);

        // Create a map to hold the combined values
        Map<String, String> combinedValues = new HashMap<>();

        // Iterate over the JSON array and combine values
        Iterator<JsonNode> iterator = jsonNode.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode item = iterator.next();
            item.fields().forEachRemaining(entry -> {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue().asText();
                combinedValues.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> v1 + "," + v2);
            });
        }

        // Create the resulting JSON object
        return objectMapper.valueToTree(combinedValues);

    }
```